# Is Outlook changing body format after attaching to ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler and why if so?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have noticed that the email formatting was changed when I do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
  //var mail = new MailForm();
  //mail.ShowDialog();

  Outlook.Application outlookApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
  outlookApp.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookApp_ItemSend);

  try
  {
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = mailItem.UserProperties.Add("MyCustomProperty", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, Outlook.OlFormatText.olFormatTextText);
    mailUserProperty.Value = "This is from my procedure";

    mailItem.Display(true); // Pass 'true' to make the window modal

    outlookApp.ItemSend -= new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookApp_ItemSend);

  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    Forms.MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
  }

}
```

The email that comes to my Thunderbird client has this:

```
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 000000006369751F17599447AC12B6C7A882F623A4732100


------=_NextPart_000_0001_01D9BE1B.AE7FB620
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef;
    name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="winmail.dat"
```

And here is the email content of the regular email (without listening to ItemSend event)

```
------=_NextPart_000_0005_01D9BE1B.B597D000
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

It seems that something is changing the email content after/before ItemSend event is attached to it. Can anyone confirm this?

**UPDATE**

I looked around a bit and found this statement:

> How to control TNEF in messages
>
> You can control TNEF by using one of three methods:
>
> Global - If you change your default email format to plain text or
> HTML, it helps make sure that TNEF is not sent **unless an Outlook
> feature needs it**.

[How to control TNEF in messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-email-message-formats-affect-internet-email-messages-in-outlook-3b2c0536-c1c0-1d68-19f0-8cae13c26722)

Can it be it: "unless an Outlook feature needs it"?

Answer (score 1):

If you set a user property, Outlook will switch to TNEF since it is otherwise impossible to preserve it in a pure MIME message.

If you need to set a custom property without forcing TNEF/RTF format, set it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. You can use the same DASL property name as the one generated when you used `UserProperties.Add`. You can see the DASL property name in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - select the sent message with the user property, click IMessage button, select the property, see DASL edit box.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry, I know that now, but the moment this hit me was so surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was because of the user property on that email:

```
  Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = mailItem.UserProperties.Add("MyCustomProperty", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, Outlook.OlFormatText.olFormatTextText);
    mailUserProperty.Value = "This is from my procedure";
```

After I removed these lines of code everything is as before.